# Hypothesis Test of Calculating P-Value for Average Height

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Question: In 2003-2006 the average height of an American aged 20-29 was reported to be 67.25. Many believe that college students are shorter than average. A random sample of students produced the following data:

n=140, mean = 65.39, s = 4.64

Type in the test statistic rounded to TWO decimal places

**Solution Attempt**: I attempted to tackle this problem by choosing its sampling distribution as 1 sample T-test. I'm given no probabilities, so I don't think it's a Z-test.

Would the setup for the formula for solving for a t-value then be: $$t = \frac{65.39 - 67.25}{\frac{4.64}{\sqrt{140}}} = -4.74$$
Taking this value then and putting into R-Studio as $p value = pt(-4.74, df = 139, lower.tail = FALSE) = .999999$

This means if I choose a 95% confidence interval ... I fail to reject right? Because .9999 >> ..05

Comment: For sufficiently large n, there is very little difference between the t and z distributions (in fact, that is pretty much exactly what the t distribution was designed for).

Comment: Because T < 0, you want 'lower.tail=T' in R studio for a P-value essentially 0.